# Parallels Plesk Panel 9.5.4 fails to load up after upgrade to 11.0.9

Tags: panel, plesk, parallels

I am facing annoying problem.
My hosting provider sent me an email that my Plesk panels version is too old and it needs to be updated. So I logged to my Parallels Plesk panel, and clicked update, I've chosen the latest release and got confirmation email that upgrade was successful.

After that my domain now loads up with Horder web mail log-in form, not my web page.
And when I try to log in to my Parallels Plesk panel I get:

```
ERROR: Zend_Db_Statement_Exception
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'psa.smb_apsPackages' doesn't exist

0: Pdo.php:234
Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(array)
1: Statement.php:300
Zend_Db_Statement->execute(array)
2: Abstract.php:479
Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(string 'DESCRIBE `smb_apsPackages`', array)
3: Abstract.php:238
Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(string 'DESCRIBE `smb_apsPackages`')
4: Mysql.php:169
Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable(string 'smb_apsPackages', NULL null)
5: Abstract.php:835
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupMetadata()
6: Abstract.php:874
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupPrimaryKey()
7: Abstract.php:982
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->info()
8: Select.php:100
Zend_Db_Table_Select->setTable(object of type Smb_Db_Table_Broker_ApsPackages)
9: Select.php:78
Zend_Db_Table_Select->__construct(object of type Smb_Db_Table_Broker_ApsPackages)
10: Abstract.php:1018
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->select()
11: Abstract.php:1331
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchAll(string '`name` = 'osTicket'')
12: Abstract.php:150
Db_Table_Abstract->findByFields(array, boolean true)
13: Abstract.php:162
Db_Table_Abstract->findOneByFields(array)
14: Config.php:14
HelpDesk_Config::getHelpDeskInstances()
15: NavigationContext.php:342
NavigationContext->_fetchHelpDeskSectionNodes(object of type UserAdmin)
16: NavigationContext.php:196
NavigationContext->fetchCustomButtonsSectionNodes(object of type UserAdmin)
17: NavigationContext.php:70
NavigationContext->fetchSection(object of type UserAdmin, string 'custom_buttons', array)
18: NavigationContext.php:402
NavigationContext->get(object of type UserAdmin)
19: Navigation.php:95
Navigation->getUserContextList(object of type UserAdmin)
20: Navigation.php:113
Navigation->getRoot(object of type UserAdmin)
21: Navigation.php:357
Navigation->buildPathbar(string '/license.php3', NULL null, object of type UserAdmin, string 'dashboard')
22: Navigation.php:348
Navigation->getPathbar(NULL null)
23: Navigation.php:144
Navigation->detectCurrentUpLevelURI()
24: Abstract.php:303
Form_Abstract->_getUpLevelLink()
25: Abstract.php:312
Form_Abstract->renderPathbarButton(object of type Navigation, NULL null)
26: Form.php:109
Form->assign()
27: license.php3:75
```

Any suggesttions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [bug in libmysqlclien15](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?258266-Plesk-update-to-10-4-error) from third-party repository.

Try this solution http://kb.parallels.com/en/113737